# Prevent screen from locking on Android

Tags: android, xamarin

**android xamarin code**

```
        lockctl = ((PowerManager)GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.PowerService)).NewWakeLock(
           WakeLockFlags.Partial, "tag"); //cpu  on
        lockctl.Acquire();

        WifiManager wifi = ((WifiManager)GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.WifiService));
        lockwifi = wifi.CreateWifiLock(Android.Net.WifiMode.Full, "wifilock");
        lockwifi.SetReferenceCounted(true);
        lockwifi.Acquire();
```

`

I am making a cctv app. The problem is that the screen turns off after a day.

I want to keep this screen on.
I want the screen to stay on even after several days

Answer (score 2):

If your app is running foreground, you can keep the screen on by add the following code into the each activity's OnCreate method of your project:

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
             ....
          this.Window.AddFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
        }
```

Or you can just add the `android:keepScreenOn="true"` in the every layout.xml file, such as:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

For more information, you can check the [offical document about the keeping screen on](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#screen).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you can use to keep the screen awake and never goes off while your application is running.

```
 getWindow(). addFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
```

This is one of the flag we can set to make the screen awake.

Put this inside your activity ex:- MainActivity inside onCreate().